# Show odt page count in file explorer

Tags: windows, odt

In file explorer I have the pages column but for LibreOffice files it doesn't list the page count.

Is there a way to view the page count from file explorer tab?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Apparently that is a Microsoft proprietary field. However, if you can view page count in a DOC or DOCX file, simply save the LibreOffice Writer document in that format!